# Java: Updating java arrays from user inputs of client class

Tags: java

```
public class BannerUser 
{
    private int [] userId = new int[20]; 
    private int [] courseNumber = new int[20];
    private final String [] courseName={"Math" , "History", "English", "Art", "Science"};

    public int getUserId() {
        int [] tempUser = new int[userId.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < userId.length; i++)
        {
        tempUser[i]=userId[i];
        }
        return tempUser;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        this.userId[i]=userId;

    }
    public void displayCourses() {
    for (int i=0; i < courseName.length; i++){
        courseNumber[i]=i + 1;
    System.out.println(courseNumber[i] +"\t"+ courseName[i]);
    }

    }
    public void registration (int courseNumber){
    if (courseNumber < courseName.length)
    {
        for (int i=0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            this.courseNumber[i]=courseNumber;
        }
    }


    public void displayArrays()
    {
    System.out.println("Student ID\tCourseNumber");
    for (int row=0;row<userId.length;row++){
        System.out.print(userId[row] +"\t"+ courseNumber[row]);}
    }
```

}

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class BannerUserClient {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    BannerUser bannerUser = new BannerUser();
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean done=false;
    int userType; 
    int userId;  
    int courseNumber;
    //int [] userId = new int[20];
    for (int i =0;i<20;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter user ID:");
        userId=scan.nextInt();
        bannerUser.setUserId(userId);
        do{
            System.out.println("enter\n(1) for faculty services\n(2) for student services:");
            userType=scan.nextInt();
            if (userType==1) {
                System.out.println("Under Construction");
                System.exit(0);
        }
            else if (userType==2) {
                done=true;
                bannerUser.displayCourses();
                System.out.println("Enter a course number");
                courseNumber=scan.nextInt();
                bannerUser.registration(courseNumber);
                //bannerUser.
            }
            else
                //System.out.println("invalid input!");
                bannerUser.displayArrays();
        } while(!done);
    }
}
```

}

Sorry if this looks bad.  Basically, I am taking an intro to programming course at my school and I've been stuck the past couple of units.  For this project, I have to create two separate classes: private and public.  I need to take an input from users 20 times to assign student IDs and update array userId.  After they input their ID, they need to pick a class from 5 different choices.  The class they pick should update array courseNumber. After all this, I need to display both userId and courseNumber values.  The arrays don't print at the end and I'm not even sure if the arrays are being updated. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried running your program yet?

Comment: It runs but terminates at the end without printing the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is really bad

```
public int getUserId() {
        int [] tempUser = new int[userId.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < userId.length; i++)
        {
        tempUser[i]=userId[i];
        }
        return tempUser;
    }
```

In above method you are return integer array bt return type is integer so it wont even compile.

You have net written code properly. You should think of Object-Oriented approach.